# Dependency Injecting an empty module into a controller in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I am trying to dependency inject a module into another—the former is simply an empty module.

```
angular.module('module1', []);
angular.module('module2', [])
.controller('Module2Ctrl', ['module1', '$scope', function (module1, $scope) {
  $scope.expression = 'hello!';
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="module2">
  <body ng-controller="Module2Ctrl">
    <h1>{{expression}}</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

I'm getting the dreaded `Unknown provider: module1Provider <- module1 <- Module2Ctrl` message.

What's going on? I believe everything is defined as it should be—though `module1` has no definitions, I can't find information anywhere on what would stop this from working.

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/goMVFRNuPgG6iIpGYI1Y?p=preview

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You inject providers (such as factories, services, ...), not modules. Remove the module1 injection and it will work. What you're thinking of doing is probably declaring module2 as a module dependency of module1:

```
angular.module('module1', ['module2']);
```

and then `ng-app="module"`.

Answer (score 1):

`angular.module` can not injected inside a `controller`,Only one `angular.module` can be injected inside another module.

angular.module('module2', ['module1'])

You should never do that angular. Only angular components are inject-able like service,controller, factory, filter, provider,etc.

For initializing angular on page you could do `angular.bootstrap`

```
angular.bootstrap(document,["module2"])
```